# Storing file in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, silverlight

In Isolated Storage File are stored some where deep in the tree level that is some two or 3 subfolders are made inside that files are stored . Is it possible to store in One level  that is  this is Isolated Storage path "\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is\Myfiles".My files will have all the files which I am storing.

Is it Possible to store my files in place other than the Isolated Storage

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add Folders to the IsolatedStorage-Path by just creating a Folder in your Isolated Storage.

But all Files and Folder you create in/as IsolatedStorage are stored under the path that the system has choosen.